# hash sort comparision with quick sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am reading about peformance of hash sort comparisionw with quick sort as below in Algorithims in Nutshell.

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/algorithms-in-a/9780596516246/ch04s08.html

> With 26 buckets, once n >256, Hash sort begins to quadruple its
>   performance as the problem size doubles, showing how too few buckets
>   leads to O(n^2) performance.

> ```
>     n     26 buckets    676 buckets     quick sort
>     256   0.000051      0.000062        0.000045
>     512   0.000108      0.000093        0.000098
> ```

Note, n is the number of inputs, and time is in seconds.

My question what does author mean by "ash sort begins to quadruple its performance as the problem size doubles" from above data?, and how with few buckets it is O(n^2)

Comment: That it gets 4x better performance with 2x the data to sort...!? With a little more context we may be able to clarify more...

Comment: @ deceze I added a link above, can you explain with data given how pefromance is improved with 2x data.

Comment: The paragraph after the link is a direct quote from that book.  Please format it accordingly.  I've tried twice to make the edit myself but you've made other edits in the meantime that have conflicted with mine.

Comment: Well, with the added context, it sounds like "quadruple the performance" means it becomes 4x slower. A bit awkward/incorrect phrasing there I'd say.

Comment: this: [empirical orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth). but your data shows about ~ n^1.1 (for 26 buckets, and qsort), not n^2 ?

Comment: you didn't copy the whole table; next rows indeed show how the time grows 4x with 2x the size increase. i.e. the n^2 rule.

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct types of hash tables: open and closed. It appears that you are referring to open.

In an open hash table with k "buckets" (or "slots"), each bucket is typically implemented as a (singly) linked list. Empty slots contain a null pointer. When multiple entries hash to the same slot (a collision) they get appended to the the linked list after checking for duplicates [generally duplicates are not counted again]. For insertion, time complexity can be O(1) up to O(n) for degenerate cases [see below].

Lets consider an open hash table with n entries and k slots. It is possible to have degenerate cases that leads to O(n) for a ***single*** lookup, for example when all of the entries hash to the same slot, the hash table behaves like an unordered linked list. Even if the hash function more or less uniformly spaces out the data if n >> k then time complexity ***for a single lookup*** is O(n/k), but since k is a constant this is the same as O(n).

The only way I could envision O(n^2) behavior is in the context of ***multiple*** lookups. This, I believe, is a non-standard way of looking at hash table time complexity.  However, if one's perspective is looking at a batch of n lookups after n insertions, in the degenerate case, I suppose the batch complexity could be viewed as O(n^2).

BTW, a common way of avoiding the second degenerate case is to double the number of slots (buckets) and re-hash whenever n grows larger than (initial) k.  This operation of resizing (up-sizing) the hash requires O(n) time and requires a dynamic hash function that can double its output range. This operation amortizes over time leading to O(log(n)) amortized insertion -- the advantage being the possibility of retaining O(1) amortized lookup.